# How do I add a button to an existing group on the code context window?

Tags: vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I'd like to place a command button directly underneath the View Call Hierarchy button on the context window.

I've only been able to add a button at the very bottom of the entire menu using `IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN`.

Is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the menu item position is controlled by the Button **priority** attribute. And you can find other button priorities using the [Command Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandExplorer) extension. But I didn't try it myself.

Comment: You save the day once again Sergey, thank you!.  That extension helped me see I needed to use <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CODEWIN_NAVIGATETOLOCATION" /> as the parent of my button.